# MySQL: Stored function not accepting null from view field

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-functions

I have the following query that call stored function:

```
select count(*) 
  from vw_estatus_empleados vw
 where nivel_color_id('Cumplimiento', vw.estatus_actual) = -1;
```

The `nivel_color_id` function returns `-1` when second parameter is null.

Actually, **the `vw.estatus_actual` field have `null` in all rows**.

When I run the query above the results is:

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
```

By other hand, when I run the same query with `null` instead of `vw.estatus_actual`:

```
select count(*) 
  from vw_estatus_empleados vw
 where nivel_color_id('Cumplimiento', null) = -1;
```

The result is:

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       19 |
+----------+
```

Here is the function header:

```
CREATE DEFINER=... 
FUNCTION `nivel_color_id`(`escala` VARCHAR(16), `valor` FLOAT) 
RETURNS int(11)
```

Why this could happed?

**Edit:**

A view row sample:

```
SELECT * FROM vw_estatus_empleados 
 WHERE estatus_actual IS NULL;

+-------------+--------------+----------------+
| id_empleado | id_proveedor | estatus_actual |
+-------------+--------------+----------------+
|          11 |           16 |           NULL |
|           8 |           11 |           NULL |
|           4 |            2 |           NULL |
|          19 |           23 |           NULL |
|          13 |           18 |           NULL |
+-------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your vw.estatus_actual is actually set to NULL and not just an empty space ' '?

Do a `SELECT * FROM vw_estatus_empleados WHERE estatus_actual IS NULL` and see what is returned.